# Initialize a List<T> with inline definition of <T>

Tags: c#

You can always define a class like this:

```
public class item {
  int id;
  string name;
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
List<item> items = new List<item>();
```

Can we not do something like this:

```
var items = new List<{int id, string name}>();
```

Just a short way of initializing when underlying object definition is simple and predictable.

This is possible in JavaScript (I have seen examples in Angular).

Sorry if this is answered before, my quick search could not find an answer to this specific topic on Google or SO.

Comment: Look at tuples (C#7).

Comment: You can define tuples to do the same

Comment: `var items = new List<(int Id, string Name)>()`

Comment: Not sure why this is voted down, it's a valid question.

Comment: @Sem why did you delete your answer? It was a good option

Comment: @ZoharPeled I was trying to add some code explanation before getting downvoted :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C# 7 introduces [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples), so you can do this:

```
var list = new List<(int id, string name)>();
list.Add((3, "Bob"));

var (id, name) = list[0];

var entry = list[0];
string s = $"{entry.name} has ID {entry.id}";

foreach (var (id, name) in list)
{

}
```

Before C# 7 you can use the old `Tuple` type, which is a bit more messy:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(3, "Bob"));

foreach (var item in list)
{
    int id = item.Item1;
    string name = item.Item2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the old tuple sucks. I hated the `.Item1` so much I've never used them :-) +1 for being faster than me :-)

Answer (score 7):

In c# 7.0 and higher you can use value tuples - the syntax is almost identical:

```
var items = new List<(int id, string name)>();
```

Answer (score 7):

Also you can do it like this:

```
var list = new[] { new { Id = 1, Name = "name" } }.ToList();

list.Add(new { Id = 2, Name = "name2" });

foreach (var item in list)
{
    int id = item.Id;
    string name = item.Name;
}
```

References: [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), [Implicitly Typed Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/implicitly-typed-arrays), [ToList Extension Method](https://www.dotnetperls.com/tolist)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) ;-) *edited because I pasted the wrong hyperlink*

Comment: You don't need to create a dummy item (which might be expensive if too much data inside). https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwD4AEAMACFBGA3AWACh0tsAWA4gZiwCYMBhIgbyI3dIDYsaAZAS1gAeACoA+RgjgR4A4eIAUKAKyiJAEwCuYMAE8AlBgC8EgHZwA7hjkw1C/ZQ5csZDAFkI/U/bYdWhJycANwgEDAAbQRhjSWlZKIV7YzNLDGYMAEl1GOwMAF8HX0CIqIA6AEF1dQVzK3SsmLJ6AscOPKI8oA

Comment: @Vlad I agree, I just tried to keep it simple (quick answer).